# Как запустить программу с правами пользователя?

Tags: delphi, windows-7

Как запустить программу с правами пользователя? Через Delphi и если можно, то и без пароля от администратора.

Answer (score 2):

Повышение прав средствами UAC не самая тривиальная задача, но в MSDN [эта тема довольно неплохо рассмотрена](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx).

Еще есть интересная [презенташка](http://pascalfonteneau.developpez.com/articles/delphi/vista/uac/VistaUACandDelphi.pdf) на эту тему.

ЗЫ. Пароль админа вводить скорее всего придется.

Comment: К сожалению, это не то...

Comment: а что именно вас интересует?

Comment: Как создать bat файл не имея прав админа? А то у меня ОШИБКА:

Fail access denied(доступ запрещен);

=(

Comment: А вы его в какой директории создаете?

Comment: В C:\ !!! Потому что в *.bat файле прописано самоудаление программы и на рабочия стол создавать нельзя(и в другие папки, которые несут в пути имя пользователя) У меня имя пользователя написано русскими буквами и при выполнение bat файла русские буквы коверкаются и файл не найден!

Comment: в 7ке для записи в корень `С:\` нужна права админа. Сохраните хотя бы  в `C:\TEMP`. Или разберитесь с "коверканьем букв".

Comment: С C:\ProgramData не надо прав админа =)

Comment: Не надо писать временные файлы в c:\ProgramData. Если нужно создавать временные файлы, то лучше уж получить переменную, указывающую на временную папку. В Delphi это просто:   function WinTemp: string;  
begin  
 SetLength(result, MAX_PATH);  
 SetLength(result, GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, PChar(result)));  
end;